# UIImagePickerController crashes app | Swift3, Xcode8

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3, xcode8

*FYI: I´m new to Swift so this might be a really simple problem but I just can´t figure it out.*

I have been following the [Start Developing iOS Apps (Swift)](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/Lesson4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH6-SW1) tutorial using the Xcode 8 beta and Swift 3.

I attached a Tap Gesture Recognizer to a Image View and then added this action in the ViewController.swift :

```
@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

When the selectImageFromPhotLibrary Action is called by a tap on the Image View the app crashes without showing the ImagePicker.

I guess that the problem is with the new **present** instead of **presentViewController** which was introduced in Swift 3

---

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {

    // MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        //  Handle the text  field´s user input through delegate callbacks
        nameTextField.delegate = self
    }

    // MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
    }

    // MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
        // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
        let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
        photoImageView.image = selectedImage

        // Dismiss the picker.
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }


    // MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        // Hide the keyboard.
        nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

        // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
        let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

        // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

        // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
        imagePickerController.delegate = self

        present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }


}
```

---

Console Output

```
2016-06-20 17:08:20.568093 FoodTracker[33322:696094] bundleid: com.armin.FoodTracker, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, propagate_with_activity: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:20.569458 FoodTracker[33322:696094] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: HIDEvents, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:20.604909 FoodTracker[33322:696090] Created DB, header sequence number = 288
2016-06-20 17:08:20.668341 FoodTracker[33322:696090] Created DB, header sequence number = 288
2016-06-20 17:08:20.743143 FoodTracker[33322:696090] subsystem: com.apple.BaseBoard, category: MachPort, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:20.769881 FoodTracker[33322:696091] subsystem: com.apple.FrontBoard, category: Common, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:22.007665 FoodTracker[33322:695971] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Touch, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:22.009799 FoodTracker[33322:695971] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: Gesture, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:22.012973 FoodTracker[33322:695971] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:22.013820 FoodTracker[33322:695971] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
2016-06-20 17:08:23.061815 FoodTracker[33322:695971] subsystem: com.apple.photos, category: Generic, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 0, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 0, privacy_setting: 0
```

Comment: You'd think that when posting about an error, it'd be useful to post the error.

Comment: You call a wrong method. You should call like this: self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: @AMomchilov there is no error message. The app just closes/crashes

Comment: Check the console after it crashes

Comment: @abraaoan I already tried that initially but then i get a error saying: "presentViewController(_:animated:completion:) has been renamed to preent(_:animated:completion:)"

Comment: @AMomchilov Added the console output in the question

Comment: `self.presentViewController(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)` is an example of the old Swift syntax specified in the instructional material. When Xcode is updated to Version 8.0 (8A218a), it prompts the user to update any old Swift syntax it finds to Apple Swift version 3.0 (swiftlang-800.0.46.2 clang-800.0.38).  The ViewController.swift code shown above uses the new syntax.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Add this key to your `info.plist`,

```
Key : Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description [ NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription ]
String Value : We need access to your camera roll and photo library, so that we can do operations on it. [ Customise it in your own way]
```

That's it, `Clean & Run` the project.

[image]

Comment: You don't set the value to `YES`. You set it to a short message that is displayed to the user.

Comment: @rmaddy Yeah right, they have changed it in the new Xcode. I have modified my answer.

Comment: Good catch. I'd recommend [filing a bug to Apple](http://bugreport.apple.com) about that tutorial so you can follow it getting fixed.

Comment: Also, you should need only "Photo Library Usage Description" for this project, not "Media Library Usage Description". The latter is for using frameworks like MediaPlayer to access Music and other iTunes-synced content, which this tutorial project doesn't do.

Comment: @rickster Yeah you are correct. I forgot about that, I just put it there to give an overall concept about these new keys. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Same for NSCameraUsageDescription - if you launch the camera without it, you get an extremely unhelpful crash.

Comment: Another issue I found after I implemented this fix was that I was creating an image format with an unknown type. Changing AnyObject to Any fixed this:

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {

Comment: For video add the Privacy - Microphone Usage as well or it will still crash.

Comment: Thanks, it help me very much!

Comment: For me the dismiss is not working. When i click on the button 'use photo' the camera pop up again and again. Is there a way to make it work?

Answer (score 15):

In xcode 8 new key is added Privacy For -

**Media,Location,Photo Library,Reminders,Motion,Calender,Bluetooth,HomeKit,Camera,Contacts** etc.. and value is Description for the privacy you will access for.For ex. "We need access to use photo library to make functionality work" or ANY_YOUR_APP_RELATED_DESCRIPTION.

[image]

Comment: tnx, helped me to visualize

Comment: Why are the values set to "YES"? They should be short messages that are shown to the user.

Answer (score 9):

Noticed a camera key and value needed for camera usage as well.

Keys required for both the camera and photo library that need to be in the info.plist:

```
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access needed to use your camera.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>Access needed to photo gallery.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried adding the privacy messages but those didn't work for me. Then I looked at the Attributes Inspector for the image element itself and checked the box 'User Interaction Enabled', which had previously been unchecked. After doing this, the picker worked. Hope it helps someone.

Comment: For me the dismiss is not working. When i click on the button 'use photo' the camera pop up again and again. Is there a way to make it work?