# UIImagePickerController in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uiimagepickercontroller, swift3, ios10

I've recently updated to Swift 3 in Xcode 8 using the developer beta.
I'm trying to implement Firebase Auth, and everything's going well.

My Problem:

I'm trying to upload an image as a user's profile picture to a Firebase database.

I thought I could use the `UIImagePickerController` to do this, but when I do, I get a

> "Thread 7: Signal SIGABRT

I know what this would normally indicate, but I checked, and my image does indeed print my test statement when I tap it.

My failed method:

ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Photos

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var passWordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var nameTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid != nil {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let view = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ProfileViewController")
            self.present(view, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleSelectProfileImageView)))
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        self.emailTextField.delegate = self;
        self.passWordTextField.delegate = self;
        self.nameTextField.delegate = self;
    }

func handleSelectProfileImageView() {
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()

    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true

    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

I'm not sure yet if this is just a problem with Swift 3 and the developer Xcode 8 beta, or if I'm just doing it the wrong way for swift 3.

EDIT:

I'm using the GM Version of xcode8, but still get that same error.

[image: Screenshot]

[image: screenshot2]

[image: screenshot3]

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: BTW - you shouldn't be using a beta version of Xcode 8 any more. Use the GM version.

Comment: @rmaddy okay. I'll try using the GM version.

Comment: where you get error? because code you have post in question seems alright!! are you getting error in `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` ?

Comment: @KetanParmar I'm pretty sure it's presenting the UIImagePickerController as a view controller that's giving me the error.

Comment: See http://www.raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug a crash. Once you do that, update your question with the actual code causing the crash and point out the exact line causing the crash.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think  you need to add `privacy - key` for camara and photo library in your `info.plist` file as from `xcode 8`. for example,

```
 Key : Privacy - Media Library Usage Description
 Value : YES 

 Key : Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
 Value : YES 

 Key : Privacy - Camara Usage Description
 Value : YES
```

here value is  `string` not `Boolean`.

so try this.

Check [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html) for more details!

Reference : [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925583/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-app-swift3-xcode8)

Comment: I'll reply back if it works once I get to try that method out.

Comment: This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 1):

Follow the error message from xCode, and add key/value to `Info.plist` of application.

For example, I got an error message from my developing app. It reminds me to add `NSCameraUsageDescription` to app's Info.plist.

---

#### The error message from xCode

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive
>   data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain
>   an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the
>   user how the app uses this data.

---

#### And MORE

Add `key/value` pair to `Localizable.strings`, it will give `i18n` support.
For example, I add a pair to `Localizable.strings (English)`. It will give English description when ask user about camera permission.

```
"NSCameraUsageDescription" = "We needs camera permission to capture image.";
```