# Using device CAMERA ON IOS 10 causes the application to be terminated

Tags: ios, ios10, xcode8

Error in console
[access] This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description. The app's Info.plist must contain an NSCameraUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428916/uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-3/39429884#39429884](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428916/uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-3/39429884#39429884)

Comment: It's shocking that Apple gets away with stuff like this.  Last week, my iPhone app worked, this week (following an iOS upgrade), it crashes completely when a user tries to take a photo.  No error... no suggestion of what happened, just an angry user.  They are seriously the most developer-unfriendly company I've dealt with since Palm....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I Solved This issue:-** 
Go to info.plist - Your Xcode bundle
Click the "+" and go down the resulting list until you see  "Privacy - Camera Usage Description". Add this item to by clicking it inside that list.

**Format**
..-Info.Plist
Key :- Privacy - Camera Usage Description
Type :- string
Value :- empty - Don't enter anything

Just clean xcode project and run it ... it's worked for me.