# Activating iPhone camera action crashes my app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, camera, viewcontroller

Strange issue:

My users activate the iPhone camera by tapping a button to take a photo. E.g. button is tapped, camera opens. Up until yesterday, the code below worked completely fine (and still does on my own phone). However, on everyone else's phone in our test group, the app crashes as soon as the camera button is tapped. Any idea as to why? See my code below - I'm stumped. ***Note***: Everyone is running iOS 10.

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,  UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

}    
    @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *photoData;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

    @end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)takePhoto:(id)sender {

    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    self.imageView.image = chosenImage;

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}

- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {

    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Please, when you post a question about a crash, you must include the complete and exact error message from the crash and point out the exact line of code causing the crash.

Comment: @rmaddy The only reason I didn't this time is because I can't SEE the crash error (convoluted, I know). On my device, it works swimmingly. However it seems to be crashing on other devices (which I can't plug into my own computer)...

Comment: Get the users to send you the crash report.

Comment: @rmaddy Assuming they're not super tech savvy - how can they do that? Is there something in their settings? Never really had to ask for it ha ha.

Comment: Settings -> Privacy -> Diagnostics & Usage -> Diagnostics & Usage Data. Then they need to find the latest entry for the app and view it. Then painstakingly select all of the text and then email it to you.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is crashing only on `ios10` then it may be the problem of `privacy key setting` which is mandatory in `ios10` and `xcode 8`. so you need to add below `key`,

```
  Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description
```

to in your `info.plist`. and it may solve your issue i think. otherwise your code is perfect.

You can refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428916/uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-3/39429884#39429884) for more key and it's description!

Comment: You should vote to close the question as a duplicate instead of reposting your answer over and over.

Comment: Trying it now - this answer would make sense because it crashes on every device but my own! Report back shortly :)

Comment: @Brittany But you state everyone is running iOS 10. You never stated that you are not using iOS 10.

Comment: @rmaddy : yeah, agree with you!! haven't thought like that i should close it. Btw voted to close now!

Comment: @rmaddy I am running iOS 10. Just grabbed crash reports from my users - it is the Privacy issue. Nice work.