# iOS 10: sharing image/save image started crashing

Tags: ios, share, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have a code which shares a line of text and an image via UIActivityViewController. After I updated to iOS 10 it started crashing with the following log:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I do not post the code since it seems to happen even in Apple's own example. I found a corresponding [radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/27988819), but not StackOverflow topic.

Hope it will save someone's time. The fix is to add that line to your plist even though the app itself does not interact with the Photo Library. If anyone finds a better solution, it would be nice.

Please, note that it is different from a [problem with UIImagePickerController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925583/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-app-swift3-xcode8) - it is close to an opposite action.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UIImagePickerController crashes app | Swift3, Xcode8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925583/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-app-swift3-xcode8)

Comment: Always [search on the error](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Info.plist+must+contain+an+NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription+key) before posting a question.

Comment: @NiravD UIImagePickerController allows choosing an image from the gallery. This post is about an opposite action - sharing an image. And unlike the situation with a picker, the programmer does not specify that he wants to save it in photos - it is chosen by user.

Comment: @rmaddy I did and did not found a similar one. You also marked it as a problem with iOS 10, not Swift 3, which seems to be wrong. The same code runs fine in my older apps on the same phone. Those were built with Swift 2.

Comment: It's a new requirement under iOS 10 when your app is built with a Base SDK of iOS 10. The language is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes @rmaddy is right that suggested answer do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

Add NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription to Info.plist :-( Don't leave it empty - it reuses Apple's default question, but it is fine only for development. Uploading such archive to App Store will trigger an error.