# iOS Swift 3 UIImagePickerController crash

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, xcode8

I upgraded project to Swift 3 and I am getting a crash on the line (at various points/viewControllers in the project) :

```
present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

in the function:

```
@IBAction func userImage(_ sender: AnyObject){
    print("button pressed")
    let picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = false
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil) // -> crashes here
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
    let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
    self.imageToPost.setImage(newImage, for: UIControlState())
    self.imageToPost.imageView?.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

The crash message in the console:

```
libsystem_kernel.dylib`__abort_with_payload:
0x11108d138 <+0>:  movl   $0x2000209, %eax          ; imm = 0x2000209 
0x11108d13d <+5>:  movq   %rcx, %r10
0x11108d140 <+8>:  syscall 
->  0x11108d142 <+10>: jae    0x11108d14c               ; <+20>
0x11108d144 <+12>: movq   %rax, %rdi
0x11108d147 <+15>: jmp    0x111086d6f               ; cerror_nocancel
0x11108d14c <+20>: retq   
0x11108d14d <+21>: nop    
0x11108d14e <+22>: nop    
0x11108d14f <+23>: nop
```

in my in info.plist I have:

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) photo gallery use</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use </string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) microphone use</string>
```

I looked around and did see that having NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription and  NSCameraUsageDescription in info.plist solves the issue ([UIImagePickerController in Swift 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39428916/uiimagepickercontroller-in-swift-3) and [UIImagePickerController crashes app | Swift3, Xcode8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925583/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-app-swift3-xcode8)), but it doesn't for me. I did clean and build, restarted xCode, restarted Mac, etc.

It might be worth pointing out that my console at startup says:

```
objc[11204]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/AssetsLibraryServices.framework/AssetsLibraryServices (0x11a0d8910) and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator.sdk/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PhotoLibraryServices.framework/PhotoLibraryServices (0x119f02210). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

but according to this thread that doesn't matter https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63254

my class has the delegates:

```
class PersonalSettingsVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITextViewDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
```

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Set Two delegate => UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate

Comment: Hi, the two delegates are there. Appreciate you answer.

Comment: @PeterdeVries from which point your app crash...

Comment: you need to give a permission to camera for access.

Comment: @seggy the app crashes after "button pressed". I also tried:         present(picker, animated: true) { 
            print("succes")
        } , which does not appear in console. I gave camera access in info.plist , do I need to do that as well in VC?

Comment: not its not necessary

Comment: check My Edited post. Its working 100% cause I have tested it on IOS 10

Comment: Did you try it ? Just as I suggest

Comment: Did you reset your simulator after changing the plist?

Comment:  BC Its working though give downvote

Comment: @AaronBrager going to try that right now.

Comment: @AaronBrager did reset, made no difference.

Comment: Give me your mail id. I will forward sample demo of it @PeterdeVries

Comment: @Jecky where do I send that

Comment: Here in comment @PeterdeVries Just enter your mail id in comment

Comment: @Jecky peterdev@hotmail.com

Comment: Ok, I send you demo, just check your mail id @PeterdeVries

Comment: @Jecky appreciate the demo, I copied everything over, still the same crash. your demo works fine on it's own. Maybe there is a clash with a framework somewhere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125497/discussion-between-jecky-and-peter-de-vries).

Comment: @PeterdeVries, I'm having exactly the same crash than you. Did you figure out the solution?
I tried to go in the Target, Info, and added the Privacy Keys in "Custom iOS Target Properties"... Nothing changed for me. Still crashing.

Comment: @manonthemoon that is exactly what I did, somehow the in "Custom iOS Target Properties" seemed disconnected from the info.plist in between my viewControllers, so I had to add them in both.

Comment: Actually, in my case, I figured it out. My issue was that I forgot to put the microphone usage description in my plist. That's why when I was switching to video, it was crashing.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so I figured it out. (3 days of my life)  Even though I put the Privacy keys in my info.plist, they were not actually accessed/ recognised by the app. so I had to go top level app -> Targets -> "MY_APP" -> info and put them there as well. after that, it ran. (Solutions from Jecky, Seggy and KAR were great, so I upvoted). obviously a bug, hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

for me it worked after I added the following in info.plist
Privacy - Camera Usage Description
$(PRODUCT_NAME) camera use

Answer (score 0):

Try My code 
It is with take picture with camera or choose from library.
 
Just give **UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate**

Set Property in Info.plist file
**Privacy - Photo Library Usage Description : Allow photo**

```
@IBAction func dsfsd(_ sender: AnyObject) {

        let actionSheetController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Action Sheet", message: "Swiftly Now! Choose an option!", preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        //Create and add the Cancel action
        let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel) { action -> Void in
            //Just dismiss the action sheet
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(cancelAction)
        //Create and add first option action
        let takePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Take Picture", style: .default) { action -> Void in
            if(  UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.camera))

            {
                let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
                myPickerController.delegate = self
                myPickerController.sourceType = .camera
                self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            else
            {
                let actionController: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Camera is not     available",message: "", preferredStyle: .alert)
                let cancelAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel) { action -> Void     in
                    //Just dismiss the action sheet
                }

                actionController.addAction(cancelAction)
                self.present(actionController, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        }

        actionSheetController.addAction(takePictureAction)
        //Create and add a second option action
        let choosePictureAction: UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Choose From Camera Roll", style: .default) { action -> Void in
            let myPickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            myPickerController.delegate = self;
            myPickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary
            self.present(myPickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
        actionSheetController.addAction(choosePictureAction)

        //Present the AlertController
        self.present(actionSheetController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }


    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {


        let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
        self.imgview.image = image

        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer very much and did come across your previous answer in another threat. it crashes with: 'presentViewController(_:animated:completion:)' has been renamed to 'present(_:animated:completion:)' using swift 3.0

Comment: Ok, I will check it

Comment: same crash, but on "Choose From Camera Roll". Great implementation though, like it!

Comment: Give me your email Id. I will forward demo to you

Answer (score 0):

**Try this for Swift 3..**

```
@IBAction func userImage(_ sender: AnyObject){
 if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary) {

            self.imagePicker.delegate = self
            self.imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.photoLibrary;
            self.imagePicker.allowsEditing = true

            self.present(self.imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
            self.imagePicked.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        }

}
```

Comment: Hi, tried this, with .camera does do nothing (no camera in simulator), when I change it to photoLibrary, same crash.

Comment: currently i am using this code in my application and also supported in ios 10 , why you give down vote.. give any wrong instruction to you?

Comment: just so you know, I appreciate all your help and am NOT down voting anyone here

Comment: @PeterdeVries ok plz check my code i am using this for camera roll in swift 3

Answer (score 0):

try this for your swift 3.0 code,

```
 @IBAction func takePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .camera
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

@IBAction func selectPhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    var picker = UIImagePickerController()
    picker.delegate = self
    picker.allowsEditing = true
    picker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    self.present(picker, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    var chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage]
    self.imageView!.image = chosenImage
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: { _ in })
}
```

It will present picker in your app and will work perfect.

Hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: Ok, now this is fine cause I have also give answer in swift 2.2 thats why I commented on it

Comment: @PeterdeVries Check my updated answer. Its working for me.

Comment: @PeterdeVries Ok. No problem. check it and give the feedback

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `NSCameraUsageDescription` key to your PrettyApp-Info.plist file with some text description.