# UITapGestureRecognizer isn't triggering properly

Tags: ios, swift, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm fairly new to the iOS development and I'm following Apple's tutorial on developing apps so please bear with me. I am currently developing in Swift 3 on XCode 8

I'm at a point in the tutorial where I connected a UITapGestureRecognizer to an image view on the storyboard. I have written code to implement the action to pick out a photo from the library and place it into the image view. When I run the simulation and click on the image view, there is no pop up asking the app access photos or anything. Below is the code I have written

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {


// MARK: Properties
@IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    //  Handle the text  field´s user input through delegate callbacks
    nameTextField.delegate = self
}

// MARK: UITextFieldDelegate
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
}

func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
    mealNameLabel.text = textField.text
}

// MARK: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate
func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    // Dismiss the picker if the user canceled.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    // The info dictionary contains multiple representations of the image, and this uses the original.
    let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

    // Set photoImageView to display the selected image.
    photoImageView.image = selectedImage

    // Dismiss the picker.
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}


// MARK: Actions

@IBAction func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    // Hide the keyboard.
    nameTextField.resignFirstResponder()

    // UIImagePickerController is a view controller that lets a user pick media from their photo library.
    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()

    // Only allow photos to be picked, not taken.
    imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary

    // Make sure ViewController is notified when the user picks an image.
    imagePickerController.delegate = self

    present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

@IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
}
```

}

Here is the console output before and after I click the image view

```
2016-10-25 13:11:05.115607 TestApp1[17930:1007384] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureEnvironment, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0  
2016-10-25 13:11:05.116342 TestApp1[17930:1007384] subsystem: com.apple.UIKit, category: GestureExclusion, enable_level: 0, persist_level: 0, default_ttl: 1, info_ttl: 0, debug_ttl: 0, generate_symptoms: 0, enable_oversize: 1, privacy_setting: 2, enable_private_data: 0
```

Based from the post below, I have also selected and added the "Privacy -  Photo Library Usage Description" key into info.plist but also no dice.

[UIImagePickerController crashes app | Swift3, Xcode8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37925583/uiimagepickercontroller-crashes-app-swift3-xcode8)

How can I get the photo library to pop up?

Comment: Where's the code that creates and sets up the tap gesture?

Comment: Have you bound the recognizer to the controller?

Comment: @rmaddy I am guessing what you are looking for is under the function name selectImageFromPhotoLibrary which is located near the bottom of the code.

Comment: @OnurTuna Do you mean if I dragged the tap gesture recognizer from the scene dock to the view controller file? If so, then yes.

Comment: You should bind that recogniser to a property defined in your class. Did you?

Comment: @LampPost Your guess is incorrect. That's the method that the tap gesture is supposed to call. But where and how is the tap gesture setup?

Comment: I don't think I bound the recognizer to a property defined in my class. Following the tutorial, I located the tap gesture recognizer from the object library, dragged it into the image view on the storyboard. Then control-drag the tap gesture recognizer onto viewcontroller.swift and changed the connection to action and changed the type to UITapGestureRecognizer. From there I added code and nothing else. I really appreciate the help you guys are giving!

Answer (score 5):

Have you enabled `isUserInteractionEnabled` to **true**?

```
self.photoImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
```

If you have setup everything nice and fair, you might be missing this step. Also check in `selectImageFromPhotoLibrary` function using Debugger whether the Debugger comes in it or not when you tap your `photoImageView`.

In order to setup Tap Gesture by code, write this in your `ViewController` class.

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(selectImageFromPhotoLibrary))
self.photoImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

func selectImageFromPhotoLibrary(sender:UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    //open photo library code here
}
```